Using a 32bit audio channel to transport 2 16-bit audio channels, preferrably with ffmpeg
I have been looking for this a lot, and seems to be either really stupid or really insane idea, because I can't find anything about it...
I have the problem that I want to push 3 or 4 channels through a system which supports only two, but at any depth. So theoretically I can use the low 2 bytes of the left 32bit channel for one audio channel, and the high two bytes for another, ditto for the right channel, and actually carry 4 channels (and unmix them on the other side).
If I don't do floating point and integer only, there should be no loss, and I don't intend to listen to it while in the system, just when it's out.
Any ideas if something already exists for this type of muxing/demuxing?
Update (that I'll also put in a comment), some more context:
I have a voctomix 1 instance in the middle, which is an audio/video mixer. It can only pass two audio channels, no matter what they are. I control the input and output, but I need 3 channels...
I am also trying to replace the voctomix with its newer version, but that's a separate (and probably larger) can of worms.

This technology exists, it’s Dolby Pro Logic. Trying to encode the two channels in one is doomed to fail unless it really is all losslessly digital.

also, what is the point in having 4 audio streams in a file if only 2 are supported? you can't magically hear all 4. You could combine them and convert surround to stereo, or better, use something like Dolby Pro Logic, as Daniel B suggests. Also, if a weird mechanic is required to get all 4 streams again, then what stops you from having 2 separate files?

It's most certainly not stupid.  It's creative as hell, but I'd have to vote for insane idea.  My big question would be, why?

Some more context:
I have a voctomix 1 instance in the middle, which is an audio/video mixer. It can only pass two audio channels, no matter what they are. I control the input and output, but I need 3 channels...
I am also trying to replace the voctomix with its newer version, but that's a separate (and probably larger) can of worms.

Please add more details to the question. What exactly do you plan to do with the audio/video mixer? If you (somehow) encode 3 or 4 audio channels in 2, wouldn't the mixer damage the encoded data when it handles the data like a known audio format?

The audio/video mixer is a software one, and it just copies the audio. There's no modification of the audio itself.

If the audio/video mixer is software, could you run 2 instances at the same time?

This is basically what the SMPTE 302 and 337 standards do but these standards work with MPEG-TS.
